# I'm trying to implement merge sort but the output i get is the same array

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort but the output i get is the same array.this merge sort gives me the same output as input.plz help.i'm pretty sure the implementation is correct and i tried debugging it but couldnt figure out the mistake.

Solved: i was comparing helper[left] to helper[mid] instead of helper right. Thanks for the help people.

```
public class Sort {

  public static void main(String[] args){
     int arr[] = {3,5,6,9,0,2,4};
    Sort sort = new Sort();
    int i=0;
    sort.MergeSort(arr);
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
  }


  private void MergeSort(int[] arr2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int helper[] = new int[arr2.length];

    MergeSort(arr2,helper,0,arr2.length-1);


  }


  private  void MergeSort(int[] arr2,int[] helper,int start, int end) {
    if(start<end){
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        MergeSort(arr2,helper,start,mid);
        MergeSort(arr2,helper,mid+1,end);
        Merge(arr2,helper,start,mid,end);


    }else{
        //do nothing
    }

  }


  private  void Merge(int[] arr2, int[] helper, int start, int mid, int end) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++){
        helper[i]=arr2[i];
    }
    i=start;
    int left = start;
    int right = mid+1;
    while(left <= mid && right <= end){
        if(helper[left] <= helper[mid]){
            arr2[i] = helper[left];
            left++;
        }else{
            arr2[i] = helper[right];
            right++;
        }
        i++;
    }
        //move remaining of left to array
        int remaining = mid-left;
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<=remaining;j++){
            arr2[i+j]=helper[left+j];
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: well your not returning anything on Merge, your then asking it to print your input so what do you expect?  You should return arr2 in Merge and maybe print this

Comment: is this really mergesort? O.O

Comment: @dave Arrays are mutable in Java. Changes to the *contents* of an array in a method will be visible outside it.

Comment: Just as a note - convention in Java is that methods are named in `lowerCamelCase`.  It was honestly quite confusing for me to see the `Merge` (etc.) methods capitalised, since I kept parsing them as class names.  It will be very helpful for others reading your code if you are consistent with the conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky one... :-)

you are always comparing the element at `left`to the element at `mid` instead of the element at `right`:

```
while(left <= mid && right <= end){
    if(helper[left] <= helper[mid]){
```

should be

```
while(left <= mid && right <= end){
    if(helper[left] <= helper[right]){
```

Optional, but more clear:
Besides as Matt mentioned you are missing to catch up remaining values from the right arm

```
while (left <= mid)
    arr2[i++] = helper[left++];

while (right <= end) {
    arr2[i++] = helper[right++];
```

Edit: Mark right arm catchup as optional

Comment: Guess I was typing too much of a rant about coding style, unit tests and debugging techniques in my own answer to be the first one to post this. +1, these 2 things fix the code.

Comment: hmm, now I don't think it is necessary to catch up the right arm as the values should be already at the correct place

Comment: Strictly speaking - it's not needed. However this is not code golf. The less such unobvious optimizations - the better. OP was already lost in 3 variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's that your merge() function is missing a certain case.

```
 //move remaining of left to array
 int remaining = mid-left;
 int j;
 for(j=0;j<=remaining;j++){
     arr2[i+j]=helper[left+j];
 }
```

takes care of if the right sub-array was exhausted first, but does not consider the case if the left sub array was exhausted first (which may lead to some unusual results). I know this wasn't quite what you were trying to ask and I will keep looking at your code to see if I can help.

Happy Coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: I dont think it is explicitly necessary (but surely more readable) to catch up the right arm after the left one got exhausted. That's because the assertion `right == i` holds after the left arm has gotten exchausted (`left == mid+1`). The values in `arr2` are at the correct place already (as assured by previous mergesort runs to that right subarray) and catching up the right arm just copies the same values (`helper[right + j] == arr2[i + j]`).